# C++ Using unions or inheritance to parse data

Tags: c++, parsing

I have a scenario where I receive binary data in a buffer (from a com port, or a socket, or some other producer, etc.).  The data received is interpreted in different ways, typically keying off the message header in the first byte or first few bytes.  I am looking for the best class structure to handle and parse data like this.  This seems like it would be easy to develop, but for some reason it is not apparent to me.

One option I came up with is using unions in a POD type class.  For example:

```
class Message {
  public:
    void DoSomething();

    int packetId;
    union {
      struct packetType1 { int A, int B, ... };
      struct packetType2 { float M, short N, ... };  // may be different size than packetType1
      ...
    };
};

void Message::DoSomething() {
  switch (packetId) {
  case 1:
    // do something using packetType1
    break;
  case 2:
    // do something using packetType2
    break;
  }
}
```

Is it acceptable practice to pass a pointer to such an object into a function that takes a buffer as input?  This compiles and appears to work.  For example:

```
Message msg;
recvfrom(sock, (char*) &msg, sizeof(msg), ...);
msg.DoSomething();
```

One downside to this is the member variables in `Message` are public.  I would rather make them private and provide read only access methods. If the member variables in `Message` are made private (or protected), does this still work?  I think no, but am not sure.

I have considering using inheritance, but the issue is one doesn't know which derived class is needed until after the data has been received and the header parsed.  This example compiles and appears to work, but this seems like a bad approach.

```
class Message {
  virtual void DoSomething();

  int packetId;
};
class PacketType1 : public Message {
  void DoSomething();

  int A, B;
};
class PacketType2 : public Message {
  void DoSomething();

  float M;
  short N;
};

void Message::DoSomething() {
  switch (packetId) {
  case 1:
    ((PacketType1 *) this)->DoSomething();
    break;
  case 2:
    ((PacketType2 *) this)->DoSomething();
    break;
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
Message* msg = (Message*) new unsigned char [MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE];
recvfrom(sock, (char*) msg, MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE, ...);
msg->DoSomething();
```

What are the best practices for a scenario like this?  Please be gentle, I am not a software guy by trade or schooling, but sometimes out of necessity.  This is one of those times. :-) Thanks.

EDIT: A couple folks have mentioned endianness.  I forgot to mention in the original post that the message source could have the same or different endianness than my system, but this is known a-priori.  My intention is for one of the Message class methods to handle this when necessary. For example:

```
void Message::ByteSwap() {
  ByteSwap4(packetId);      // helper function that byte swaps a 4-byte word
  switch(packetId) {
  case 1:
    ByteSwap4(A);
    ByteSwap4(B);
    ...
    break;
  case 2:
    ByteSwap4(M);
    ByteSwap2(N);          // helper function that byte swaps a 2-byte word
    ...
    break;
  }
}
```

For method one, I neglected to mention that I have to use the compiler directive `#pragma pack(1)` in the .h file that defines the Message class to force members to be byte aligned.

With regard to the source of the messages, I have no control over those systems.  What I do have is formal documentation that defines the byte structure of the message being sent.

Thanks to all for your input!

Comment: where does `packetId` come from?

Comment: Received as part of the message data.  In this example, the first four bytes of the message make up the packetId.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second method is completely broken, as you're getting a sequence of bytes in `recvfrom` and then interpreting this as a non-POD type, which is undefined and likely to crash, as `Message` probably needs a vtable and whatnot set up for it which is unlikely to be correct unless the data being received was sent by the exact same process on the same machine.  Even if the sender is running identical code on an identical machine, it probably won't work.

The first method gets into all kinds of implementation-defined details about padding and alignment of the structs and unions, but may work ok as long as the sender was built with the same compiler targetting the same architecture.  Its most likely to be ok if you use the fixed-size types from stdint.h and carefully arrange things so that padding is unlikely to be needed for alignment, but you still have potential issue with endianness if you try to do this between different architectures.

The best way to do this is to bite the bullet and define your message as a byte stream and write code to explicitly convert an object into a bytestream and build a new object from a bytestream.  One way that works reasonably well is an inheritance hierarchy with a virtual encode and static decode method:

```
class Message {
    virtual void DoSomething();
    virtual size_t Encode(char *buffer, size_t limit);
    static Message *Decode(char *buffer, size_t size);
};

class Type1 : public Message {
    virtual void DoSomething();
    virtual size_t Encode(char *buffer, size_t limit);
    static Type1 *Decode(char *buffer, size_t size);
};

Message *Message::Decode(char *buffer, size_t size) {
    if (size < 1) return 0; /* or throw some exception */
    switch(buffer[0]) {
    case 1: return Type1::Decode(buffer, size);
    case 2: return Type2::Decode(buffer, size);
    default: return 0; // or throw an exception
    }
}
```

**edit**

You can leave out the encode methods if you don't care about encoding -- but if you're creating code for both ends of the communication, it makes sense to keep the Encode and Decode together so they remain consistent.

The Decode methods are static because they are called before an object of the decoded type exists (before you even know what that type is, even).  They create an object based on the message and return that.  So continuing a bit, you might have:

```
Type1 *Type1::Decode(char *buffer, size_t size) {
    if (size != 9) return 0; // or throw an exception
    Type1 *rv = new Type1;
    rv->A = extract4byteInt(buffer+1);
    rv->B = extract4byteInt(buffer+5);
    return rv;
}

int extract4byteInt(char *buffer) {
    return ((buffer[0] & 0xff) << 24) +
           ((buffer[1] & 0xff) << 16) +
           ((buffer[2] & 0xff) << 8) +
           (buffer[3] & 0xff);
}
```

Note that we're making the size, padding, and byte ordering of all the parts of the message explicit here, rather than relying on however the compiler happens to lay things out.

Comment: there seems to be no reason to encode the message again, at, the Questioner tells only about receiving messages. the rest is just a other form of my example ...

Comment: sure, but if i want to parse the proprietary message from a System XYZ from Vendor ABC, i don't care about Encoding ....

Comment: @Chris The second method was actually my first attempt. It does work, but I recognize it is broken. Thus the first method, which was my second attempt. In your example, Where is the message data saved? In the base class or derived? Why are the derived `Decode` methods static? So the derived class can be inherited again?

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your apporach is alignment of class member fields in memory. Alignment is not guaranteed to be equal with different compilers or platforms. Also, you need to consider little endian / big endian issues.

So, in order to be save, you should parse the data yourself. You could first read the 'packetId' and dependent on that value you parse the remaining data. You could e.g. define different parser classes for each message type. Then, dependent on the 'packetId' you use the right class instance to parse the concrete message.

Answer (score 0):

As your messages sizes could be different, i would use inheritance, different structs and a wrapper function.

```
struct MessageType1_t {
  int A, B;
}

class Message
{
  public:
  virtual Message(unsigned char * message)=0;
  virtual ~Message()=0;

  virtual void DoSomething()=0;

  Message * create(unsigned char * message)
  {
     // get first four bites and check message type
     // create a new instance of the derived class you need and return it
}

class PacketType1 : public Message {
public:
   void PacketType1(unsigned char * message)
   {
      myMessage = (messageType1_t *)message;
   }

   void DoSomething()
   {
      // do something
   }

private:
   MessageType1_t * myMessage;
};
```

The code is not complete, just the idea. Make sure you that your platform uses the same endiantype as the source system of the message. Or take care to correct the byteorder

Comment: I have a question with this approach.  It would seem that every time a message is received and `Message::create` is called, the derived class would have to be created in `create` dynamically using `new`. Is there any downside to repeatedly allocating and deallocating memory like this as messages are received?  Would deleting the base pointer free the derived object?

Comment: @Mike the `Message *` pointer could be reused. As the class is very small, there should be not performance problems with that. Deleting the base pointer will also free the derived object. You could just keep a pointer to the message, instead of coping it inside the classes, so there is only a very small amount of memory to be allocated.